# how to create paths and bump up the texture

Tags: bump

im stuck at this point
i manage to add the image texture both sides to create the skin
but what i want to do is to trace every vein and bump them up a very little so i can create a second layer over the model

im kinda new on this so im asking the experts here

basically i want to create every vein and make them part of the model

any ideas?
thanks !

[image]

Comment: If you mean that you want the drawing to be sculpted on the surface of your object, you could use a Draw brush in Sculpt mode and use your drawing as a texture? But don't you want to fake it with a Bump node?

Comment: Yes, correct. 
I want to create channels between the white and the black so I can give them a little bump up effect like if the paint is over the model. Regarding your ideas, 1) draw brush on sculp mode, I tried sculp mode before and the lumps were really heavy and big. Is there a way to make micro bumps? Like tiny squares each pass? 2) I don’t really understand what you meant about fake it with a bump node. (I’m kinda new on this). Thanks for the help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use your black and white image as a bump map to create fake 3D relief. Blur your image a bit, in the *Shader Editor* create an *Image Texture*, load the image, plug the node into the *Height* input of a *Vector > Bump* node that you plug into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*. As youcan seeit creates a 3D pattern while actually I've just use a simple plane with n subdivision:

[image]